# Patch DEM data gap with raster calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, arcgis-10.5

I have DEM data with some gaps that I want to patch with lower resolution DEM. Using raster calculator on ArcMap 10.5, I used this syntax:

```
Con(IsNull("original.tif"),"lowres.tif","original.tif")
```

But I always get the same error message (of a syntax error). I don't understand what mistakes I did with this process. I've checked the file names, and I didn't type it manually (I double-clicked it from the selection window).

Comment: Whats your gis software ?Are you sure about the raster names?  one of the raster names are lowres. Don't type  names. just select rasters to type the names automatically. Don't use format type (tif) if it's not in the names

Comment: I'm using ArcMap 10.5, and yes, I've checked the file names multiple times, and I didn't type it manually. I used the double-click selection method from the selection window.

Comment: I used your con syntax with own rasters. It's ok. Do you use raster calculator?

Comment: What is your precise error message?